# Access VBA SQL syntax, errors 3061 and 3075

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to Access VBA, I am using SQL statement to get data for creating excel file. The query uses a combo box [FBrpt_FbReason_Cbo] value as a criteria for the data. This is the first code I modified from the Access Query SQL mode:

```
SQL = "SELECT FB_Register.FB_Date_Received AS [Date received], FB_Register.FB_Resp_date AS [Response date], FB_Register.FB_Title AS [Feedback title], FB_Register.FB_Reason AS Reason " & _
                "FROM FB_Register " & _
                "WHERE (((FB_Register.FB_Reason)=[Forms]![Feedback_Reports]![FBrpt_FbReason_Cbo])) " & _
                "ORDER BY FB_Register.FB_Date_Received DESC; "
```

It returns the error - `Error number: 3061 = Too few parameters. Expected 1.`
I then modified the Where line to:

```
"WHERE FB_Register.FB_Reason = " & [Forms]![Feedback_Reports]![FBrpt_FbReason_Cbo] & _
                " ORDER BY FB_Register.FB_Date_Received DESC"
```

This returns the error – `Error Number: 3075= Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ‘FB_Register.FB_Reason = Positive feedback’.`

In this case I have `"Positive feedback"` selected in the combo box. This code `‘FB_Register.FB_Reason = Positive feedback’` looks to me how it should be. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed the extra quotes - I believe - to turn the value into a string, even though its already a string

```
"WHERE FB_Register.FB_Reason = '" & [Forms]![Feedback_Reports]![FBrpt_FbReason_Cbo] & _ "' ORDER BY FB_Register.FB_Date_Received DESC"
```